# Is there a technical limitation for android on replacing windows laptops?

Tags: android-studio

I mean why google does not make android for laptops so basically most people just use office apps on windows, can android for laptops replace windows for most people?

What is the hardest part of replacing windows with android for laptops?

Is the android emulator of android studio a full android version?

Comment: You DO get Android for laptops/PC's - its just not commonly used, and the project appears to be languishing - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android-x86 Also relevant is https://www.google.com/chromebook/chrome-os/ and its "not hardware bound" cousin chromium-os

Answer (score 1):

There's two major technical limitations if you are talking about running standard well-accepted Microsoft software on an Android system.  These are high level overviews without a lot of details.

- Android is a different operating system than Windows.

  - Programs use operating system calls to interact with the hardware and user.  Different operating systems have different types of calls and ways to represent the hardware.
  - There are various ways of "simulating" one OS in another but it can make things slower or not work properly if not done right, and you need to account for all corner cases and undocumented interactions with the operating system to be 100% reliable.  Microsoft is notorious for using undocumented APIs in its products.
- Android runs a different type of CPU than most Windows PCs.

  - It's possible to build software for a different type of CPU, if you have the source code and a build environment.
  - Some software is written in a CPU-independent scheme, but you still need the runtime on the CPU you want to target.
  - Microsoft owns the source code to its products and doesn't allow others to build for different CPUs.
  - You still need the operating system it needs working on the CPU.

> What is the hardest part of replacing windows with android for laptops?

Not really anything technical.  People don't want to have to learn new software or deal with unexpected bugs brought on by moving software to a different platform.  No one really cares about the operating system, they care about their applications.

The Microsoft Office suite is particularly interesting because:

- many people use it for work and form productive habits that they don't want to change unless there is a good reason,
- it has a lot of capabilities many people don't use, but they expect them to be there when needed.

> Is the android emulator of android studio a full android version?

It probably is.  Android's base, AOSP is an open-source project so anyone can take the code and build Android for any CPU.  Android also has a number of features that allow programs to run independent of the type of CPU (using similar technologies to Java).  Android on x86 (PC hardware) is a thing.

Comment: I mean android already works on x86 very well an example is the android emulator, android already has microsoft office apps so no simulation required, making it work should be 100x easier than what apple is doing woth arm macs

Comment: You do not get the "full" applications on android. More often than not they are cut-down or rewritten versions that lack many of the features that have been added, in some cases, over *decades* of development. What you might consider "good enough" is woefully lacking for people used to the full application. Android is also a touch centric operating system and is poorly optimised for keyboard and mouse in a similar way to Windows being relatively poorly optimised for touch.